# Compilation time slow on a single computer

Tags: 14.04, compiling, performance

We are experiencing some really slow compilation times on a single desktop computer that we use as the primary workstation for a research project.

Compiling our codebase on this computer takes 42 minutes. Compile times on any other computer are significantly faster - the fastest being 7 minutes on a newer gaming laptop, and 11 minutes on my early 2011 Macbook Pro (i7-2620M). All systems are running Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit, kernel `3.13.0-45-generic` (we can not use a newer kernel due to some specific drivers we use).

During compilation all cores run at 98-100%, and I have checked that they are running at full clock speed (3.5GHz). I have also disabled Intel SpeedStep in the BIOS, and tried to use the default BIOS settings for performance. None of this seems to have any effect, and has not been necessary to do on any other computer we use.

The workstation in question is pretty new, these are the CPU specs from `lshw`:

```
*-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4b
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
          slot: SOCKET 1150
          size: 3511MHz
          capacity: 3900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
```

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4r9ytmgot7a7czx/hardinfo_report.html?dl=0) is a system report generated with `hardinfo`.

Comment: Check disk performance.  Are you using NFS, FUSE or virtualization?

Comment: Also check cpu temp (broken cpu fan means high cpu load with low performance).

Comment: Disk is tested several times, and consistently gives around 350MB/s write speeds. CPU temp maxes out and stabilizes at 100C, with all cores running at 100% during compilation.

Comment: Project's programming language and compiler are ...?. If your are using make  try to limit the number of concurrent jobs (using -j and -l options), maybe an IO bottleneck. Use iostat and dtrace to identify bottlenecks.

Comment: On the other hand… 100C… stress your CPU and compare its temp and performance with other i7-4770K (to identify a thermal paste/fan problem). In this link (http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_4770k_linux&num=1) you can find an exhaustive performance test for ubuntu+i7-4770K, compare your system with its results (they use Phoronix test suite that you can install from ubuntu repository).

Comment: C++, using gcc 4.8 as the compiler. No IO bottleneck when running at 8 or 6 cores, even tested RAM and SSD separately previously. Will try the benchmark later today.

Comment: Hah! You were right about the temp. Will post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the CPU was not cooling properly, and this wasn't reported to the OS, nor in any way did it make the system shut down.

During compilation, CPUs maxed out quickly at 100C. Running `sensors` showed that the critical limit of the CPU was in fact 100C. After dismounting the cooler, I could see that only a small patch of thermal paste had actually touched the CPU!

After reapplying the thermal paste, compilation takes 4 minutes, but the CPU still reaches 95C, so I have ordered a Cooler Master 212 EVO instead of the stock Intel cooler we have now.

I guess out IT dept. owes a round of beer for not building the computer properly.

Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can determine, you are using a 4th generation Intel core processor with a BIOS version that is too old to be used with that processor.
You should update the BIOS version from 0604 to 2403 and then re-try your benchmark compiles.

Note there seems to be some notes about needing a "BIOS updater tool first before using the new Intel 4th Gen Core processors".

[Reference](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/1/45/3/3/n2uFjfEkEIQokEMw/29/).

Comment: I will try that immediately!

Comment: Upgraded to 2403, but unfortunately no change - compilation time was 39 minutes (within the normal variation on this computer).